# Error with update statement in access

Tags: ms-access

I am new to Access, trying to update one of the access tables by looking into another access table but getting exception when I try to execute below code:

```
Update eb
SET 
    eb.LoadedDateTimeFrom = df.FromLoadedDateTimeD, 
    eb.LoadedDateTimeTo = df.ToLoadedDateTimeD
FROM 
    RhExceptionBuckets as eb 
INNER JOIN 
    ExceptionBucketTrancheDates as df 
    ON eb.TrancheTo = df.TrancheCode
    INNER JOIN 
        ExceptionBucketTrancheDates as df 
        ON eb.TrancheFrom = df.TrancheCode
```

Can someone help me with it. Giving syntax error.

Comment: The other table instance must be aliased like dt, not df again. But use the query GUI to design the query, much easier.

Comment: You need parantheses to sort out multiple joins. That is one issue. The other issue is that you are trying to join the same table ´ExceptionBucketTrancheDates as df´ twice on different attributes. What are you trying to achieve?